# Background from terminal emulator to Openbox session

Tags: terminal, xorg, openbox

Is there any way to run a command from a terminal emulator in Openbox, so that Openbox would own the process, rather than the terminal?

Then I could launch a program from a terminal emulator that would stay running when I closed the terminal emulator, but would exit when X11 exits?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just run the command in the background and exit the terminal emulator gracefully (use either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or `exit`):

```
command &
```

For example, `firefox &`.

In the BASH shell, the ampersand (`&`) means "run this command as a backround process". If you close the terminal from which you launched it **using either `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>**, the program will keep running. If you close the terminal by clicking on it's windows "X" it will also kill the process.

To bring a process back to the foreground (from the *same* terminal or tty) run `fg`. To send a process launched normally to the background, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal you launched it from.

Other ways to run processes in a way that is independent of the terminal emulator that launched them are the following (always using firefox as an example):

1. `nohup`. From the `nohup` manpage:

   > nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
   >
   > If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from /dev/null.  If standard output is a terminal,
   >      append output to `nohup.out' if possible,`$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.  If standard error is  a
   >      terminal, redirect it to standard output.  To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

   Example:

   ```
   nohup firefox
   ```
2. `at`, from the `at` manpage:

   > at, batch, atq, atrm - queue, examine or delete jobs for later execution
   >
   > at      executes commands at a specified time.

   The usage is slightly more complex, you need to have a text file that contains the command(s) you want to run, one per line. Then you launch `at`, telling it to execute at a specific time:

   ```
   echo "firefox" > command.txt
   at 14:56 < command.txt
   ```

   The example above tells `at` to launch the commands listed in the file `command.txt` at 14:56 PM.

NOTE: Using either `at` or `nohup`, the process launched will keep running after exiting X.

Comment: That doesn't work. It backgrounds the process so I can keep using the terminal, but when the terminal closes, the processes it has backgrounded close as well.

Comment: @LMJoy, that's strange, it should. Are you launching a graphical application or a CLI one? Anyway, see my updated answer for more choices.

Comment: it's the same with both GUI and CLI applications. And my issue with nohup is that the process becomes owned by init, not by xorg. So it won't exit when I exit X.

Comment: @LMJoy OK, I just checked, I get the same behavior you describe if I close the terminal by clicking the close window button (X at top right usually). However, if I exit the terminal emulator using Ctrl+D or `exit` the process keeps running. I am updating my answer now.

Comment: @LMJoy Did you ever try to run a process and the exit the terminal using `exit` or Ctrl+D? I am curious if it is a gnome and variants specific feature or if it also works in openbox.